# Digital Certificate Issue

Tags: c#, security, internet-explorer, iis, certificate

Ok, let me explain my situation.  I want to simulate communication between a client and a server.

I created a self-signed certificate called "TestCA" and installed it in the Trusted Certification Root Authorities section.

Using this self-signed certificate, I created two other certificates, one with name "ServerCert" and subject "CN=localhost:2001" and the other with name "ClientCert" and subject name "CN=www.client.com" and installed both in the Personal section of the certificates folder.

I deployed a web service in IIS as HTTPS using the certificate with subject name ["CN=localhost:2001"].  The web service was deployed on [localhost] and port 2001.  Now, when I try to browse to the web service, internet explorer gives me this error:

> The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
>
> Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.

I don't know why it is giving me this error since the subject name of the certificate is ["CN=localhost:2001"] and the web address of the website being browsed is [https://localhost:2001/].

How can I solve this problem so that IE does not display this error?

Comment: Maybe using non-standard ports (i.e. your "2001" instead of the "443") is not allowed?

Comment: @UweKeim I don't know.  I can still browse the website if I ignore the error though and the data is still encrypted using HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port number is not relevant when you create a certificate.
Please create certificate for localhost with the subject name `localhost` (not `CN=localhost`, but `localhost`).
You will be able to access to localhost without warnings.
Also, for www.client.com please create certificate with the subject name `client.com` (not `CN=www.client.com`)